# If $g(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$, and the following are true, how to determine the interval in which $ g(2)$ lies?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, solution-verification

$$g(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$$
and $$f(t) \in\left[\frac{1}{2}, 1\right] \forall t\in [0,1]\ \text{ and}\  f(t) \in \left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right] \forall t\in [1,2]$$
I have been aksed to find the interval in which $g(2)$ lies.
To solve it, I first differentiated both sides, thus obtaining

$$g'(x)=f(x)\tag{1}$$
from which I can deduce $g'(2) \in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$, but from this, how can I deduce the interval in which g(2) lies?

then, I attempted to find g(2), which is
$$g(2)= \int_0^2 f(2)dt$$, beyond which, I'm stuck, what should I do from here?

Comment: *“find the interval in which it lies”* – What is “it”? Do you mean the interval in which $g(2)$ lies?

Comment: $g(2)= \int_0^2 f(2)dt$ is wrong, it should be $g(2)= \int_0^2 f(t)dt$.

Comment: @MartinR,yes, Ido

Comment: Oh, OK, thanks,

Comment: You have a lower and an upper bound for $f$. If you substitute that in $g(2)= \int_0^2 f(t)dt$ then you get a lower bound and an upper bound for $g(2)$.

Comment: that just gives the lower bounds for f(t) though, how does that give me the bounds of $\int_0^2 f(t)dt$?

Comment: @fhhh bounds on $f$ also give you bounds on "the area below $f$'s graph, which is that integral

Comment: @fhhh One can also use the *Mean Value Theorem.* See my answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: @David, oh, OK Thanks!

Comment: @esoteric-elliptic, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Mean Value Theorem,
$$g(2) - g(1) = g'(\xi_1) = f(\xi_1)$$
for some $\xi_1\in (1,2)$. Also, $$g(1) - g(0) = g'(\xi_2) = f(\xi_2)$$
for some $\xi_2 \in (0,1)$. Observe that $g(0) = 0$, and thus,
$$g(2) = f(\xi_1) + f(\xi_2)$$ for some $\xi_1\in (1,2)$ and $\xi_2 \in (0,1)$. With the constraints on $f$, we can see that
$$\frac12 \leqslant f(\xi_1) + f(\xi_2) \leqslant \frac32$$
which gives
$$\boxed{\frac12 \leqslant g(2) \leqslant \frac32}$$

Comment: Thanks! This MVT for integrals is similar to that for differentials(LMVT), right?

Comment: @fhhh I am using the differential form of the MVT. $g(b) - g(a) = (b-a) g'(c)$ for some $c\in (a,b)$. In our case, $g'(c) = f(c)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$g(2)=\int_0^2f(t)dt= \int_0^1f(t)dt+\int_1^2f(t)dt$$
Now, for the minimum of $g(2)$, each integral in the above equation must be minimised. This happens when $f$ assumes its least possible values on each of the intervals constituting its domain, i.e. $$f(t)=\begin{cases}\frac12, & t\in[0,1] \\ 0, & t\in[1,2]\end{cases}$$ Then the minimum of $g(2)$ is $\displaystyle \int_0^1\dfrac12dt+\int_1^20dt=\dfrac12$.

Similarly, for the maxima, we maximise each part and it happens when $$f(t)=\begin{cases}1, & t\in[0,1] \\ \dfrac12, & t\in[1,2]\end{cases}$$ Then the maximum of $g(2)$ is $\displaystyle \int_0^11dt+\int_1^2\dfrac12dt=1+\dfrac12=\dfrac32$.

Note that $\left[\dfrac12,\dfrac32\right]$ is the TIGHTEST bound possible because the end points are actually achieved for some value of $f$.